# adding the values of y axis on matplotlib plot, with the plt.annotate command misplaces the text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following x, y axis data:

```py
genres_list = ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Documentary', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Horror', 'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'War', 'Western']

f1_score= np.array([0.40423036, 0.16336633, 0.57195574, 0.5243328 , 0.811918  ,
        0.3756098 , 0.9379653 , 0.9969197 , 0.02926829, 0.8402032 ,
        0.17272727, 0.13152805, 0.25016633, 0.6125356 , 0.30035087,
        0.02531646, 0.60923076], dtype=np.float32)
```

I create a matplotlib graph like the main idea is to plot the f1 score per genre and check if for some labels my neural network cannot achieve a high f1 score. Since I do this on Colab's Dark mode, I change the color of labels and axis to white.

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (13,10)
              
ax.plot(genres_list, f1_score)
                
ax.set_title('F1 score per genre tag')
ax.set_xlabel('Movie Genre')
ax.set_ylabel('F1 score')
ax.set_xticklabels(genres_list)

# plt.title('F1 score per genre tag')
# plt.xlabel('Movie Genre')
# plt.ylabel('F1 score')
                
ax.spines['left'].set_color('white')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('white')
                
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
                
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('white')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('white')
ax.title.set_color('white')

rects = ax.patches #this is an empty [] list for an unknown reason.

for rect, label in zip(rects, f1_score):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height + 5, label,
            ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

ax.annotate(f1_score, (0.8, 0.8))
plt.show()
```

To annotate the text I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart). But the solution given in that question it seems that does not fit in my case.

The output is this, I clearly do something wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like f1 score labels to be displayed against each point. So far as I'm aware `ax.annotate` will not accept arrays so you need to annotate one point at a time by replacing `ax.annotate(f1_score, (0.8, 0.8))` with  something like;

```
for i, f1 in enumerate(f1_score):
    ax.annotate(round(f1, 2), (i, f1))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Ty for the answer. It actually works. I have added also the output on your answer. Do you now how can I move a little bit the numbers so not to fall upon the blue line?

Comment: @NikSp [ax.annotate(text=round(f1, 2), xy=(i, f1+0.5))](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).

Comment: That's often a challenging problem with line plots. You can manually add an offset as per @Ynjxsjmh 's response or you can try using the `ha` (horizontal alignment) and `va` (vertical alignment) arguments to move the label around the coordinate (some examples in the docs https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html). FWIW in your case I would also consider using a bar plot as the x-axis is categorical not continuous. This would also make labelling easier!

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh its a solution, not very pretty one because +0.5 totally messes the position of my tags, but I guess this is due to the range of y axis (range(0,1)

Comment: @ame actually bar plot is a better option because the genres are independent to each other